# HashMap.put() Override already excisting value even the Key value is different

Tags: java, android, string, hashmap

This question has been asked earlier. But any of those replies didn't resolve my problem. Somebody please help.

I have two HashMaps,
`final HashMap<String,String> dataList = new HashMap<String,String>();`
`final HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> full = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();`

This is my code.

```
            int i=0;
            for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                i++;
                String id = "Name "+String.valueOf(i);
                strArray.add(snap.child("email").getValue().toString());
                String name =          snap.child("FirstName").getValue().toString() + " " + snap.child("LastName").getValue();
                dataList.put("Name", name);
                dataList.put("Email",snap.child("email").getValue().toString());
                dataList.put("Mobile", snap.child("Mobile").getValue().toString());
                dataList.put("Birthdate", snap.child("birthdate").getValue().toString());
                System.out.println("Datalist " + dataList);
           full.put(id, dataList);}
```

I expect to have, `{Name 1 = {Birthdate=2012/02/15, Email=gwcsathsara@gmail.com, Mobile=, Name= },Name 2 = {Birthdate=2012/02/15, Email=xc, Mobile=8524, Name=Sdcc Kkn}}`

But it overrides the excisting value. This is the result I get,
`{Name 1={Birthdate=2012/02/15, Email=xc, Mobile=8524, Name=Sdcc Kkn}, Name 2={Birthdate=2012/02/15, Email=xc, Mobile=8524, Name=Sdcc Kkn}}`

Somebody please help me with this problem. Comment if you need more information.
Thank you

Comment: You're using the same `Map` instance each time through the loop. Create a new `Map` instance for `dataList` each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add this line: `HashMap<String,String> dataList = new HashMap<String,String>();` before this line: `dataList.put("Name", name);`.

What is happening is that you are re-using your `Map`, thus you are overwriting the keys each time, with the final result being the last child you have processed.

Comment: Hey Thank you very much. I didn't realize that. Thanks again.